# Angular E2E testing getting hidden elements to show only during E2E

Tags: javascript, css, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

Currently I am using `browser.executeScript` to change hidden elements to show up during E2E.

In my app.po.ts, I have a function to set `display` to `inline`.

```
    browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style.display = "inline"',getHiddenElements());
```

By default, the hidden elements have css `display = none` so it won't show up during prod/dev.

My hidden component template:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}

<div class="hidden">
   ...... my hidden elements .......
</div>
```

Problem: The code in hidden component runs when the elements are hidden too. I prefer not to run it. Currently I am trying to have a conditional check in the component code to check for the hidden element css `display` style but I am unable to achieve it with `Renderer2` or `ElementRef` to get the css `class.hidden`.

How can I ensure that codes in hidden elements only runs during E2E testing, but not during dev/prod mode? Is there anyway to check if `.hidden.display` is none or in-line in `hidden.component.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style.display = "inline-block"',getHiddenElements());
```

**or**

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style.display = "block"',getHiddenElements());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code you have here is similar to what I have in my question. I understand that this line of code "SHOW" the hiddenElements in E2E. But what should we do to detect that in hiddenElement.component.ts? I need something in the component to check if the hidden element is visible, then run some "code"